# Kreyszig Section 2.4 Question 2

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

In section 2.4, Kreyszig proves a result stating how linear combination of linearly independent vectors can only be large in norm if it comes from large scaling coefficients:

Consider a set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of linearly independent vectors in a normed (linear / vector space) $(X,||\cdot||)$ of any dimension. Then there exists a $c>0$ such that for every choice of scalars $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}\subset K$ we have $$ \Vert\alpha_1 x_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n x_n\Vert \geq c(|\alpha_1| + \cdots + |\alpha_n|).$$

There is a question in the problem set. 'What is the largest possible $c$ in the result above if we consider the standard basis in $X=\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^3$?'

It seems so simple that it is strange, so I wanted to check my answer.

$$\Vert(\alpha _1,\alpha_2)\Vert^2 \geq c^2 (|\alpha_1| + |\alpha_2|)^2$$
If we are looking for the 'largest' $c$, I am assuming that we require $c$ to be independent of the coordinates so we can take $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ so rearranging requires $c \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So the largest can be deduced. Similarity, for $\mathbb{R}^3$ we should have  $c \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. It looks like this hints at a more general $c \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ when looking at $\mathbb{R}^n$ .

Comment: I think the $c$ in their statement is dependent on the [fixed] choice of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

Comment: @angryavian Yep I agree with you on that. In the problem $c$ changes as above as we move from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. I was worried about the dependency on  the $\alpha_j$s

Comment: Oops sorry, I missed the part in the actual exercise that asks you to consider specifically $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ as the standard basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct.
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i|
= \sum_{i=1}^n (|\alpha_i| \cdot 1)
\le \sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i|^2 \right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1 \right)}
= \sqrt{n} \|(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)\|.$$

Comment: I never seem to 'see' these clever but simple ways to apply CS.. Thanks!

Actually I didn't guess the value of $c$, I just took $\alpha_1=\alpha_2 = 1$ then rearranged the inequality where $||(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)||^2 = 2$, and $c^2(|\alpha_1| + |\alpha_2|)^2 = 4c^2$, which gives $c \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. My specific concern was with being able to choose the $\alpha_j$s so conveniently and still find the largest $c$ using this method. i.e. have I lost generality by choosing my $\alpha_j$s?

Comment: @jcm Your work by itself is not sufficient to answer the question since it only considers one possible choice of $\alpha_i$. However your specific choice happens to give the largest $c$ (for any $\alpha_i$) and corresponds to the situation where Cauchy-Schwarz attains equality.

Comment: Ah I see now - if I had chosen $\alpha_1 = 1$ $\alpha_2=0$ then I would have gotten $c=1$ which wouldn't work for other choices. Cheers!